# Azure Diagnostics - Throw exception when click on browse button

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to log diagnostics into storage account.

Throw error
[image]

Nothing happens. No dialog box.
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to check your csdef and cscfg files. If you can see any invalid configurations, they may cause issues in Visual Studio UI. In addition, everything we do in the Visual Studio UI can also be done by manually editing csdef/cscfg files. So if you can’t get this particular feature to work in Visual Studio, you can also manually modify the connection string. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758697.aspx for more information.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there was a problem installing the Azure SDK.  Have you used this before and it just started happening or is this the first time you tried to do this?

I would say uninstall/reinstall the SDK and Azure VS Tools.

Comment: Tom - I just creat a new 'Windows Azure Project' with 'ASP.Net Web Role' (at the same time); it works fine. However, in my existing project, I used 'Web Role Project in solution'; it doesn't work. Am I missing any setting? Thank you for the comment.